# Visible RelativeLayout with GridView and Buttons squeezing when a Gone layout is setVisible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout1 about half of width of screen which initially is set to GONE..and another layout  RelativeLayout2  which has to aquire the screenWidth is set Left to it..Acoording to me i set RelativeLayout1  VISIBLE it should set RelativeLayout2 to displace towards left and not squeeze RelativeALyout2 to the leftout screenwidth.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullScreen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menulayout"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/topMenubar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/slider_header"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/menu"
                android:textColor="#787878" >
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/menulist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/topMenubar"
            android:background="#232323"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="#5b5b5b"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backmenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/arrowleft" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/maingridlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/menulayout" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/topBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/handle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notificationnumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/redbatch"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/searchnow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/searchunsel" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/logolayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/handle"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/searchnow" >

                <com.drona.custom.ImageThumbLayout
                    android:id="@+id/logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
                </com.drona.custom.ImageThumbLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the layout file you have.

Comment: dont use visibility = "gone" instead of it if necessary then use visibility = "invisible"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okk what i did..I took a HorizontallScrollView with the menyLayout visible and scrollable false...then when i have to make it visible i m scrolling the view using

```
scrollTo(int x,iny y);
```

Or what i can Do i will addmenuLayout above the mainGridLayout i.e;add another child to the parent of mainGridLAyout

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0):

> android:layout_width="fill_parent"

you can try to change this i guess

Comment: no it wont work...it takes screenwidth...i need my fullScreen to expand screenWidth+200

Comment: hmm i understood give me a sec to look at your code properly.